# integrate() function in R giving error for an integrand involving for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

Could anyone explain why `integrate()` function in R gives errors for a function involving for loops or vector multiplication? I have posted here an MWE and possible errors I am getting. The same error arises if I use for loop in the `integrand` function.

```
myfun <- function(X, a, b){
  k <- 1:10
  term <- a * b * X^(k)
  fx <- exp(X) * sum(term)
  return(fx)
}

a <- 5
b <- 4

integrate(myfun, lower = 0, upper = 10, a = a, b = b)

7.412055e+13 with absolute error < 2.1
Warning message:
In X^(k) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: If X is the variable, you don't specify it.  And you did not specify a.  I think what you want is `integrate(myfun, lower = 0, upper = 10, a = a, b = b, c = c)`

Comment: Hello. When pasting code, make sure to paste it inside code block (starting and ending with tripple backtick (```)). [Check here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

**New answer based on @Shaami's comment**:

Try to work with this version of `myfun`:

```
myfun <- function(X, a, b){
  term <- 0
  for(k in 1:10){
    term <- term + a * b * X^k
  }
  fx <- exp(X) * term
  return(fx)
}
```

Then,

```
integrate(myfun, lower = 0, upper = 10, a = a, b = b)
```

**First and obsolete answer**:

Try to work with this version of `myfun`:

```
myfun <- function(X, a, b, c){

  k <- 1:10

  term <- b * a * c^(k)

  fx <- c^3* exp(X) * sum(term)

  return(fx)

}
```

Then,

```
integrate(myfun, lower = 0, upper = 10, a = a, b = b, c = c)
```

Comment: Thank you Carlo. Could you please see my editted post?

Comment: Thank you, Carlo. Your suggestions worked well. Many Thanks :)